# Keeping the indexes of deleted column

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I want to remove features with low variance in my array of data. By using scikit-learn, the code will look like below.

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold

>>> X = [[0, 2, 0, 3], [0, 1, 4, 3], [0, 1, 1, 3]]
>>> selector = VarianceThreshold()
>>> selector.fit_transform(X)
array([[2, 0],
       [1, 4],
       [1, 1]])
```

My question is how to catch the column indexes that have been deleted? Let say I want to use them to delete another array in the same column (0th and 3th column in the above example). 
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selector.get_support()` will return an array which shows which columns are kept and which are removed. In above case:

```
selector.get_support()
```

will return

```
array([False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

which means first and last indices of the original input (X) are removed.